# Show $\iint_S f(ax+by+cz) dS= \int_{-1}^1 f(t\|v\|)dt$ by cylindrical shells

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Show $\iint_S f(ax+by+cz)dS = \int_{-1}^1 f(t\|v\|)dt$ by cylindrical shells.

Here $S$ is the 2-sphere and $f$ is assumed continuous.

[Here](http://math.nyu.edu/student_resources/wwiki/index.php/Advanced_Calculus%3a_1996_January%3a_Problem_1) there are two solutions: the first of which was the one I got, and the second "by cylindrical shells". I don't understand the second method. What does his change of variable have to do with cylindrical shells?

Answer (score 0):

The reference to cylindrical shells is misleading. The idea of the method of cylindrical shells is that the variable over which we integrate is the distance **from** the axis of symmetry. In the method of *cross-sections* the variable of integration is measured **along** the axis of symmetry, and this is exactly what is happening here: $t=x\cdot a/\|a\|$. For each $t$ between $-1$ and $1$ we consider the slice of the sphere by the plane $\{x:x\cdot a/\|a\| = t\}$. This slice is a circle of length $2\pi \sqrt{1-t^2}$. Following the informal calculus approach, we give the slice some thickness $dt$ and observe that the circle thickens to a spherical belt of width $dt\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)^2} = dt / \sqrt{1-t^2}$. Hence, the area of the spherical belt simplifies to  $2\pi \,dt$. Then the integral is formed by multiplying this area by the appropriate value of $f$.

The above informal computations of the area of spherical belt could be turned into a precise statement: the part  of unit sphere between two planes $z=a$ and $z=b$, with $-1\le a\le b\le 1$, is precisely $2\pi(b-a)$: it depends only on the distance between the planes. This property is unique to our space; spheres of other dimensions do not have it.